# can some one recommend a rich text editor that's easy to customize?

Tags: text-editor

Should be light and easy to add new menus to,

like the one provided by SO here

Comment: A text editor for what purpose?  Editing text files?  A control in a web page?  A control for a Windows app?

Comment: Good question ... I was wondering the same :)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

For use in a web based application

**[WYSIWYG Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)**

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

[FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)

[Yahoo UI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

**[WYSIWYM Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)**

[WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)

Desktop applications

[NotePad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse - with a little java programming you can write plug-in which can implement whatever you want. for example currently there're plug-ins for cvs, svn, ssh, java, C++, python and ....